# How to rename all subfolders in a folder depending on name of first subfolder within each folder to rename?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO (
  ECHO "%sourcedir%.%%a\%%a\"
  )

GOTO :EOF
```

I want to edit this batch file slightly. I have the following path structure:

```
source\folders\versions
```

Each folder underneath source has one "versions" folder.

For example:

- source\component1\3.2\
- source\component2\1.3\
- source\component3\4.2\

needs to be changed to:

- source\component1.3.2\3.2\
- source\component2.1.3\1.3\
- source\component3.4.2\4.2\

What must be edited in batch code to get this folder structure from above?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch code to rename each subfolder in a specified folder by appending a dot and the name of first found subfolder of each subfolder to rename.

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=U:\sourcedir"
cd /D %SourceDir%
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ( `dir "%SourceDir%\*" /ad /b 2^>nul` ) do (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ( `dir "%%a\*" /ad /b 2^>nul`) do (
     ren "%%a" "%%a.%%b" 2>nul
  )
)
```